# Using typesafe console with play 2.1.3 and akka 2.2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, typesafe-stack

I've included the following in my Play app configuration:

```
atmos {
    trace {
        enabled = true               
        node = Node1               
    }
    send {
        warn = on
    }
}
```

I've also added this to my run configuration:

```
-javaagent:lib/weaver/aspectjweaver.jar
-Djava.library.path=lib/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4/sigar-bin/lib
-Dorg.aspectj.tracing.factory=default
```

I've included `"com.typesafe.atmos" % "trace-akka-2.2.0_2.10" % "1.2.1"` (I'm using akka 2.2.0) in my dependency list.

When I run my play app without atmos running I receive a warning about there being no receiver. When I start atmos in the background I don't receive this warning. From turning up the log level on atmos I can see it's registering something when I start my app. However when I look at the typesafe-console ui I don't see any nodes.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the warning you receive about there being no receiver is there to inform you that you also need to start the Collector. The traced application offloads its traces via a socket to the Collector and if there is no such Collector running there won't be any statistics created either.

Now to answer your question not only do you need to enable tracing but you must also make sure that all actors are traced with the *atmos.trace.traceable* flag like this:

```
atmos {
  trace {
    enabled = true
      node = Node1
      traceable {
        "*" = on
      }
      sampling {
        "*" = 1
      }
      #...
    }
  }
}
```

Finally I would like to point out that there is a [Google Group for the Typesafe Console](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/typesafe-console) should you have any more questions.

HTH
Henrik

Comment: Introducing the traceable and sampling sections have made no difference. In the console the nodes section says "Loading" for a while and then no results.

Comment: I increased the logging on atmos and shutdown the ui. My reasoning was that I should see some logging when my app connects to atmos similar to what I see when the ui connects (lots of io bridge writing bytes). However when I start my app I see no reaction from atmos. This is with the extra options you mentioned.